# How to close Selenium WebDriver code without throwing exception on closing it. Java

Tags: java, exception, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My `main()` function contains several sub-functions testing several features / scenarios etc each.
There are several cases of errors that may be found during the test running.
In each of these cases there is no reason to continue running the test so I'm sending a report email and closing the program with `driver.close();` or `driver.quit();` command.
The browser is closed however the code still trying to run so as the first command in the following sub-function still trying to do things: navigate somewhere, find objects etc but since the browser is already closed Exception is thrown as following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

or

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called.
```

So how can I tell my program to stop running and close / quit the browser properly?

Comment: You really need to look into [tag:JUnit] and/or [tag:TestNG].

Comment: No, I needed to learn more about exceptions and you could be somewhat more pleasant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a try/finally instead of a try/catch.

You don't want to catch the exception and then close the driver, you just want to close the driver at the end of the test, wherever that may be.

And example test method might look like:

```
public void exampleMethod() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    try {
        //Steps in your test
    }
    finally {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your driver.quit() inside a try/catch block.

Comment: exception caused not by `driver.quit()` command itself but by the next command somewhere in the code that trying to use the browser

Comment: Dont you think the code is not smart because why are you trying to refer to an already closed browser?

Comment: That is the question, exactly. How can I tell my code NOT to run anymore?

Comment: Why dont you put a sys.exit()

Comment: Or even a return statement.

Comment: you don't want a sys.exit, as that will bypass any cleanup code that is called by the test runner upon test completion.  a return statement would be fine though.